# FTP folder file copying from one directory to another directory

Tags: php, web

I am trying to copy a uploaded file which is in my directory called "upload" and is called image (5).jpg to my other directory called "images". This is my code.

```
<?php
       copy(upload/image (5).jpg, images/);

 ?>
```

Am I doing this right?

Comment: Yes you are, wonderful .. try to use `copy("upload/image (5).jpg","images/image (5).jpg");` instead

Comment: _It is not working though_ .. Seriously?, I couldn't come up with that, there exists something called a manual, look it up sometimes if you experience problems. [http://php.net/manual/en/function.copy.php](http://php.net/manual/en/function.copy.php)

Comment: I did but some code was their I did not understood

Comment: Yes it's very normal, it's called learning ..

Comment: @user1704671 but you know that not everyone should become a programmer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First your image file name is awful, please do not use spaces in file names. Also do not use brackets in file name. Some systems like google app engine would easily mark that as invalid file name and ignore it.

Then adjust a little your line of code to look like this:

```
$old_file = 'upload/image_5.jpg';
$new_file = 'images/image_5.jpg';

$copied = copy(old_file, $new_file);

if ($copied) {
   print "file " . $old_file . " is copied to " . $new_file;
} else {
   print "error"; 
}
```

If you encounter an error maybe paths to files are not configured right. You do not have a write permission on that specific directory etc.

Comment: haha, I am using it, please go trough my posts if you wish to check and stop insulting me. If I encounter on that kind of comment few more times that will be an end of me wasting time by helping others.

Comment: Ok. But what are you using it for? And you may want to see what insulting is. I do not see any in my question. Regards

Comment: For God's sake I am using brake tags for new lines. There is an option for that in GUI of this site so stop being annoying!

Comment: It is 1 am I am tired, programmed whole day, whole evening and I am getting up before 7 am to take kid to kinder garden before work :) so I have right to be on the edge...

Comment: Thanks i was able to use this. I would up vote up your answer  but my rank is not good.